# Show that $z^n$ is analytic. Hence find its derivative.

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that $z^n$ is analytic. Hence find its derivative.

We have $\displaystyle w=f(z)=z^n=(x+iy)^n=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$

We are asked to find $\displaystyle \frac{dw}{dz}=f'(z)$

If $z^n$ is analytic, I can calculate $\displaystyle f'(z)=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+i\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$

How do I open up $z^n$ to get u and v ? Taylor's expansion requires an independent variable.

Comment: You should explain what do you know about the problem. For instance, do you know the chain rule? Cauchy-Riemann equations? What did you try to solve this problem yourself?

Comment: CR equations are to be used to find the derivative (final step, if I may). I am not good at chain rule .. so I can't see how it may be used here

Comment: How would you prove that the function $x^n$ of the real variable is differentiable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**
Consider the quotient
$$\frac{f(z_0+\Delta z)-f(z_0)}{\Delta z}=\frac{(z_0+\Delta z)^n-z_0^n}{\Delta z} $$
and apply Newton's Binomial formula.

Comment: I understood the above answer after the comment from studiosus.Such a simple way to look at the problem !

Answer (score 4):

Of course, the method used depends on the definition of "analytic". user1337's excellent answer is based on the **Definition**: $f$ is analytic at $z$ if and only if

$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}{h}$$

exists.

I think this is the simplest and most elementary definition of "analytic". Of course, there are other equivalent definitions. For example, it is natural to consider "analytic" as satisfying a certain system of PDE's, the **Cauchy-Riemann equations**, which can be written as

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \overline{z}} = 0.$$

We should define the notation:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \overline{z}} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} - \frac{1}{i}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right).$$

I think it is worth understanding this point of view well but only once you have understood the point of view expressed in user1337's answer. I give the following exercise as practice.

***Exercise 1***:

(a) Show that $f$ is analytic at $z$ (i.e., the limit at the beginning of my answer exists) if and only if $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \overline{z}}=0$ at $z$.

(b) Show that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \overline{z}} = 0$ if and only if the differential $df$ (of the map $f:\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ viewed as a map $\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ in the natural manner) is a scalar multiple of the differential $dz$. In this case, prove that $f'(z)$ is the pertinent scalar (where $f'(z)$ is the value of the limit at the beginning of my answer).

If you have understood this point of view, then note then it remains to show that $\frac{\partial z^n}{\partial \overline{z}}=0$ in order to establish the analyticity of $z\to z^n$; furthermore, the derivative of $z\to z^n$ will be $\frac{\partial z^n}{\partial z} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial z^n}{\partial x} + \frac{1}{i} \frac{\partial z^n}{\partial y}\right)$ (why?). However, all of this is equivalent to evaluating the limit in user1337's answer.

Hope this helps!